# Change int element to str element in lxml objectify python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

Hope someone can help.

I am using lxml objectify to parse xml, which is returned from a third party integration using objectify.fromstring(). I have one element in my xml which sometimes consists of ints 0-9 only, when it is ints only the leading zero(s) are removed. As there is no set number of how many digits will be returned and the fact sometimes it may have 2 letters before the number, padding the value with zeros wouldn't suffice.

Is there a way I could specify lxml objectify to force the type to a string before doing objectify.fromstring() so it retains the value as received in the xml?

I have had a look at the lxml website but can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried making a schema? It would force data types (and, additionally, protect you from potentially harmful, unanticipated inputs) http://lxml.de/objectify.html#asserting-a-schema

Comment: I have not tried that actually. Thanks I will give it a go. Thanks for the link too, I was reading docs for a older version of lxml objectify and that didn't have the schema section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also be experiencing this kind of behavior:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> 
>>> xml = "<a><b>01</b></a>"
>>> a = objectify.fromstring(xml)
>>> print(a.b)
1
>>> print(a.b.text)
01
```

As you can see, if you get `.text` property you would get the text of the node as is.

FYI, created a follow-up topic: [lxml.objectify and leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960223/lxml-objectify-and-leading-zeros).

Comment: I will try that, Thank you very much

Comment: @Billy there is also an explanation and the possible workaround in the linked thread, check it out.

Comment: Thanks will check that out also