# lxml.objectify and leading zeros

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, lxml.objectify

When the objectify element is printed on the console, the leading zero is lost, but it is preserved in the `.text`:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> 
>>> xml = "<a><b>01</b></a>"
>>> a = objectify.fromstring(xml)
>>> print(a.b)
1
>>> print(a.b.text)
01
```

From what I understand, `objectify` automatically makes the `b` element an `IntElement` class instance. But, it also does that even if I try to explicitly set the type with an [XSD schema](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#asserting-a-schema):

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree, objectify

f = StringIO('''
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xsd:element name="a" type="AType"/>
     <xsd:complexType name="AType">
       <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" />
       </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:schema>
 ''')
schema = etree.XMLSchema(file=f)
parser = objectify.makeparser(schema=schema)

xml = "<a><b>01</b></a>"
a = objectify.fromstring(xml, parser)
print(a.b)
print(type(a.b))
print(a.b.text)
```

Prints:

```
1
<class 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>
01
```

How can I force `objectify` to recognize this `b` element as a string element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation and the behavior observed, it seems that `XSD Schema` is only used for *validation*, but isn't involved in the process of determining property data type whatsoever.

For example, when an element is declared to be of type `integer` in the XSD, but then the actual element in the XML has value of `x01`, element invalid exception is correctly raised :

```
f = StringIO(u'''
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xsd:element name="a" type="AType"/>
     <xsd:complexType name="AType">
       <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:integer" />
       </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:schema>
 ''')
schema = etree.XMLSchema(file=f)
parser = objectify.makeparser(schema=schema)

xml = '''<a><b>x01</b></a>'''
a = objectify.fromstring(xml, parser)
# the following exception raised:
# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Element 'b': 'x01' is not a valid value of....
# ...the atomic type 'xs:integer'.
```

---

Despite `objectify` documentation on [how data types are matched](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#how-data-types-are-matched) mentioned about *XML Schema xsi:type* (no. 4 in the linked section), the example code there suggests that it means *by adding `xsi:type` attribute directly in the actual XML element*, not via a separate XSD file, for example :

```
xml = '''
<a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <b xsi:type="string">01</b>
</a>
'''
a = objectify.fromstring(xml)

print(a.b)  # 01
print(type(a.b)) # <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>
print(a.b.text) # 01
```

Comment: Interesting behavior, glad to see it explained! Thanks, great answer.